# (Deleting a file/emptying it) C#

Tags: c#

Basically I am trying to make a program that empties or even deletes a certain file, the thing is, this file is about 3 or 4 or so folders past the macromedia folder, and it can be it different named folders for anyone, so that is why the string[] files is done like that, it just checks for basically "FlashGame.sol" in EVERY folder after the macromedia folder.

I commented where I need help, I basically need to empty the contents of the file, or just flat out delete it.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = textBox1.Text + "/AppData/Roaming/Macromedia"; //the person using the program has to type in the beginning of the directory, C:/Users/Mike for example
        bool Exists = Directory.Exists(path);
        try
        {
            if (Exists)
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*FlashGame.sol", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                string[] array = files;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    string info;
                    string text = array[i];
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(text))
                    {
                        info = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        //erase the contents of the file here or even delete it
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The given directory was not found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @David Yeah, and the path string has to be included in the parameters, I put "files" in it and it doesn't work (And I can't put "path" in because the path variable isn't the full path), probably because files is string[], thats basically the part I am stuck on. I'm new to C#, sorta, sorry.

Comment: What's in the `text` variable?

Comment: @David As I said I am new to C# so pardon my newbie talk, but (some of this is online tutorial read code) it looks like the text variable is a string for the array and the text string is put in the StreamReader params. So as far as I am concerned, I would assume the text variable is the actual text inside of the .sol file, unless that might be the info variable.

Comment: Well, the first thing you should do is step through this in the debugger and see what's actually in these variables, instead of guessing.  The code is a little convoluted, but if you have enough information about the file name to *read* the file, then you also have enough information about it to *delete* the file.  The file name is the same whether you're reading it or deleting it.

Comment: @David Yeah, you're right. I think I should try to find the full directory path (I don't know how to do that) and set it as a string and place it in the `File.Delete();`.
Basically I need to find a way to find the full path with only knowing the file name.

Comment: I suspect some combination of `path` and `text` will do the trick.  Also take a look at the `Path.Combine()` method, it's more versatile than putting strings together manually as it internally handles logic about constructing a valid file system path.  Once you identify in your debugger what the variables actually contain, I highly recommend renaming them to more clearly reflect what they are.  It's a small change, but it will make it much easier for you to understand your own code (and for others to understand it).  Never underestimate the importance of naming things in code :)

Comment: @David So I think I got a fix, using `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: You can't open the file in a `StreamReader` without knowing the full path and filename, and if you have that information you don't need to open it at all; you can just use `File.Delete()`. Perhaps before you start scurrying around playing with destructive actions on files, you should first learn to understand the code you're copying and pasting. It's really risky when your thought process is *I have no idea how this works or exactly what it does, but this stranger on the internet wrote it and says it will do what I want, so I'll run it on my machine and delete stuff*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear a file this way:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"file.path",string.Empty);
```

So you should probably change your Code to:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*FlashGame.sol", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, string.Empty);
}
```

Also take a look at `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`, which gives the appdata directory of the current user.

Also never [catching a Exception without handling it correctly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164256/is-catching-general-exceptions-really-a-bad-thing).  You already know, if the directory exists via your `Exists` Variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%AppData%\Macromedia\"); // Example C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\ 

if (Directory.Exists(path)) {
    string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*FlashGame.sol", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string file in files) {
        try {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```